# How to get access_token, refresh token by user id in identity server 4 in Asp net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am new to Asp.net core. I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44172221/generate-access-token-with-identityserver4-without-password/44282258) answer it works fine but i didn't get refresh token i need access_token,expiry_time and refresh token from asp.net core api for my angular application.
I want to create custom login api in which i can get tokens without using password

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As explained in the tour, this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers.You have not included syntactically valid code. Please see how to create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example that demonstrates your problem. Please take the tour at https://stackoverflow.com/tour , visit the https://stackoverflow.com/help and especially read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60394596/10422410) question too.

Comment: i want to create access token and refresh token from asp.net web api without password

Answer (score 0):

I would start by taking a look at this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client). It contians an Angular Lib for OpenID Connect & OAuth2.